# App crash first time when integrating quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox

App crashes very first time when i install it on any phone either by adb or by apk. I am pasting stack trace of crash.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
>   com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeTaskManager:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeTaskManager" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.logicspice.favorit-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.logicspice.favorit-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2738)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeTaskManager" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.logicspice.favorit-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.logicspice.favorit-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                      at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2735)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Hey did u found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Crash trace clearly points to the culprit:

```
Didn't find class "com.quickblox.messages.services.SubscribeTaskManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.logicspice.favorit-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.logicspice.favorit-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

If you're installing this unmodified, you need to log an error with the library maintainers. I would read the installation and requirements docs carefully before doing this, ensuring that you've met *every dependency*.